# SAPUI5 app cannot load the CSS file in ABAP repository

Tags: sapui5

I have one `SAPUI5` application.

I added one custom css file to it via `manifest.json` like this:

```
"resources": {
        "css": [
            {
                "uri": "css/style.css"
            }
        ]
    },
```

While this file can be loaded correctly in WEB IDE when I deploy it to ABAP repository its address does not resolved correctly. Actually it try to load the CSS file with the same address that it uses in WEB IDE and obviously it will fail.

What can cause this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the reason. I used the manifest version 4.0, and in this version the app id must be the same as the namespace otherwise it cannot resolved the addresses correctly. By making the appId and namespace equal everything going well.